# FileReader throws exception because files path has wrong syntax?

Tags: java, filereader, filenotfoundexception

I put a file to be read into my resources folder

```
src
|_main
   |_resources
     |_graphqls
       |_test.graphqls
```

The following snippet reads the file

```
final String pathToSchemaFile = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("graphqls/test.graphqls").getFile();
final File = new File(pathToSchemaFile);
```

this is the result I get when I evaluate the `File` object returned by `.getFile()` from the preceding snippet.

```
file:\C:\maven_repository\com\...\app.jar!\graphqls\test.graphqls
```

[image]

When running the following code `new FileReader(file)` this exception is being thrown

```
Method threw 'java.io.FileNotFoundException' exception.
file:\C:\maven_repository\com\...\app.jar!\graphqls\test.graphqls (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:\C:\maven_repository\com\...\app.jar.jar!\graphqls\test.graphqls (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
```

Comment: Why do you need the file, it looks like you should just use getResourceAsStream.

Comment: The GraphQL Framework expects a file that represents the graphQL schema file. Streaming it content would be my second option but I'd like to just put the file reference

Comment: Your example shows a FileReader which is an InputStreamReader, can you show the api where you need an actual file?

Comment: It is this one here: https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java/blob/master/src/main/java/graphql/schema/idl/SchemaParser.java see `line 40`

Comment: The second constructor uses a [Reader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html) so you can use the input stream.

Comment: Alright I will try that and report back if solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid the file by creating an InputStreamReader.

```
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(
    this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/graphqls/test.graphqls"), 
    StandardCharsets.UTF_8
);
```

It is advised to use `YourClassName.class.getResourceAsStream()` unless you have some specific reason to use the .getClass && .getClassLoader.

Comment: I actually have to use `.getClassLoader()` because it won't find the file otherwise.

Comment: You're using the relative pathname. So if your class is in a package, then then when it looks it up, it will look relative to the package you're in.

Comment: To be honest I do not have a lot of experience using Files and the specific filepath conventions. Is the way I do it in any way problematic? If yes - what would you recommend me to do?

Comment: @xetra11 It's good that you're using a resource instead of just using a file. The rest are detail, that are good practice but not necessary. [here](https://javachannel.org/posts/how-to-access-static-resources/) is a pretty concise but thorough article.

Answer (score 2):

You're accessing a file that is actually inside a JAR file (like a ZIP).

If your jar is on the classpath:

```
InputStream is = YourClass.class.getResourceAsStream("1.txt");
```

If it is not on the classpath, then you can access it via:

```
URL url = new URL("jar:file:/absolute/location/of/yourJar.jar!/1.txt");
InputStream is = url.openStream();
```

Comment: I know I am accessing a file that is inside a jar. But what is wrong with this approach? Why is FileReader crying like a little girl?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but as far as I know the File was used to represent something on the filesystem. And the file within the jar is not handled like any ordinary file on the file system.

Comment: Hm okay that might explain things if this is a true statement